# i want to write a python code that calculates time

Tags: python

If I leave my house at 6:52 am and run 1 mile at an easy pace (8:15 per mile), then 3 miles at tempo (7:12 per mile) and 1 mile at easy pace again, what time do I get home for breakfast?

This is what I have tried:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
>>> import datetime
>>> t=datetime.time(6,52)
>>> print (t)
06:52:00
>>> b=t+datetime.timedelta (8 hours,15 minutes)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    b=t+datetime.timedelta (8 hours,15 minutes)
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Feels like you're doing math in school and this is supposed to be solved by pen and paper. Points for creativity if I'm right :)

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `datetime.timedelta`? What data types are `8 hours` and `15 minutes` supposed to be in Python?

Comment: The datetime datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's walk it back a few steps. When you tried `b=t+datetime.timedelta (8 hours,15 minutes)`, what you were trying to do was increment your time object by 8 minutes and 15 seconds, using the `timedelta` function. In Python, functions take arguments, and `timedelta`, like any other function, has specific kinds of values you can pass for arguments. You can find them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), because since `datetime` is a library, it has nice documentation for everything. It looks like you were using IDLE which also gives you a peek at type hints:

[image]

So now we know that `timedelta` takes any one of `days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0`.

In our case, we want to add 8 minutes and 15 seconds to our original datetime object.

That would mean setting `minutes=8` and `seconds=15`.

So when we call the `timedelta` function, to avoid that syntax error, we want to invoke the function like such:

```py
b=t+datetime.timedelta(minutes=8, seconds=15)
```

And there you have it! Just remember what is and is not valid syntax in Python. Python doesn't know a thing about what you mean when you give it plain English.